# How to get the return type of a member function from within a class?

Tags: c++, clang, return-type-deduction

The following program yields a compilation error with `clang`, though it passes on other compilers:

```
#include <utility>

struct foo
{
  auto bar() -> decltype(0)
  {
    return 0;
  }

  using bar_type = decltype(std::declval<foo>().bar());
};

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

`clang` yields:

```
$ clang -std=c++11 clang_repro.cpp 
clang_repro.cpp:10:48: error: member access into incomplete type 'foo'
  using bar_type = decltype(std::declval<foo>().bar());
                                               ^
clang_repro.cpp:3:8: note: definition of 'foo' is not complete until the closing '}'
struct foo
       ^
1 error generated.
```

Is this program illegal, and if so, is there a correct way to define `foo::bar_type`?

`clang` details:

```
$ clang --version
Ubuntu clang version 3.5-1ubuntu1 (trunk) (based on LLVM 3.5)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Visual studio provides the same error (with some tiny difference in language). I think your better option is to alias the type ahead of your function declaration and then use the aliased type for your function and for whatever other purposes you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the perspective. The actual use case I have in mind (with `bar` being a member function template with parameters) would probably preclude that strategy.

Comment: Hmm, if `bar` is a template the pointer-to-member won't work either. How about doing the actual work in a static member and make the nonstatic member simply a perfectly forwarding wrapper? Then you can use `decltype` all you want on the static member.

Comment: Right, that workaround would probably do. However, I was hoping there would be a solution that did not involve much indirection and code duplication. It's a bit embarrassing that the most straightforward attempt doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: Something about this isn't making sense to me. You want to produce a type alias within a class to the return type of a function template, and the return type of said function template is determined by the template arguements? This doesn't logically work. bar_type would respresent multiple types at the same time due to multiple instantiations of the function template, which c++ doesn't allow.

Comment: @Darinth - I misspoke. The use case I have in mind involves `foo` being a class template, and `bar` returning some complicated expression of instances of `foo`'s template parameters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[g++4.9 issues the same error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c72b8dc832d38c3c)

<s>I'm not sure if this is an invalid code, because incomplete types are allowed for `declval`, and expression in `decltype` is not evaluated.</s>
[rightføld in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26435208/3959454) explained very good why this code is invalid.

You can use [std::result_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of):

```
using bar_type = std::result_of<decltype(&foo::bar)(foo)>::type;
```

Which is actually implemented like this:

```
using bar_type = decltype((std::declval<foo>().*std::declval<decltype(&foo::bar)>())());
```

The difference between this and the code in the question is that pointer-to-member operator (`.*`) is used instead of member access operator (`.`), and it doesn't require the type to be complete, which is demonstrated by this code:

```
#include <utility>
struct foo;
int main() {
    int (foo::*pbar)();
    using bar_type = decltype((std::declval<foo>().*pbar)());
}
```

Comment: it works on g++4.9, but sadly clang++3.4 still complains "invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'foo' ".

Comment: Is there any chance to make this work with an overloaded member function?

Comment: Update: [std::result_of is deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of); we must use std::invoke_result now: `using bar_type = std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&foo::bar)>`.

Answer (score 7):

§7.1.6.2 says:

> For an expression `e`, the type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>
> - if `e` is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access (5.2.5), `decltype(e)` is the type of the entity named by `e`. …
> - …

§5.2.5 says:

> For the first option (dot) the first expression shall have complete class type. …

§9.2 says:

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type (3.9) (or complete type) at the closing `}` of the class-specifier. …

`decltype(std::declval<foo>().bar())` (and in turn `std::declval<foo>().bar()`) appears before the closing `}`, so `foo` is incomplete, so `std::declval<foo>().bar()` is ill-formed, so clang is correct.

Comment: Can you explain why `decltype((std::declval<foo>().*std::declval<decltype(&foo::bar)>())())` is valid?

Comment: The semantics of `.*` and `->*` are governed by §5.5 [expr.mptr.oper] instead of §5.2.5, and §5.5 doesn't require a complete type.