# Get the result type of a std::future in a std::function

Tags: c++, c++17, future, template-meta-programming

Suppose a instance of `std:::future<T> f`, how can I get the type `T` out of it for meta programming like `decltype(f)::result_type`?
And how to get the type if this `std::future<T>` is in a `std::function<void(std::future<T>)> c`?

`std::function<T()>` for example has the member type `result_type` and `first_argument_type` (although deprecated) but I can not find any thing similar for `std::future`.

My minimized use case:

```
#include <future>
#include <functional>

#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
using callback_t = std::function<void(std::future<T>)>;

void foo (callback_t<int> callback) {
    std::packaged_task<int/*How to not write int but derive the type from callback*/()> task {
        [] () {return 42;}
    };

    task();
    callback(task.get_future());
}

int main()
{
    callback_t<int> c {[] (auto i) {
        std::cout << i.get() << "\n";
    }};
    foo (c);
}
```

Comment: something along `std::result_of(std::future<T>::get())`??

Comment: @KamilCuk I dont know `std::result_of(decltype(callback)::first_argument_type())` wont work

Comment: There is no member type you could use. As a workaround, `std::decay_t<decltype(f.get())>` should work.

Comment: I forgot to to mention in the text above the text that additionally that future is a argument in a `std::function`

Answer (score 3):

The following:

```
template<class T> struct get_first_argument_type {};
template<class R, class Arg>
struct get_first_argument_type<std::function<R(Arg)>> {
    using argument_type = Arg;
};

template<typename T>
void foo(callback_t<T> callback) {
    using the_future = typename get_first_argument_type<callback_t<T>>::argument_type;
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435084/how-to-get-the-return-type-of-a-member-function-from-within-a-class
    using your_type = typename std::result_of<decltype(&the_future::get)(the_future)>::type;
    static_assert(std::is_same<your_type, int>::value, "");
}
```

works.

Comment: Thank you so far,
but I need `foo` to be non templated. (Because of decoupling of the implementation/ compilation barrier`

Comment: then not template it? Remove `teamplte<typename T>` and replace `T` by `int`....

Comment: But that of course is nice because as soon as I template foo I need your solution, while in a non templated foo I could just write `int`, but I tried to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

In `foo(callback_t<int>)`, there's no need for

> How to not write int but derive the type from callback

because you *know* `int` is the parameter, it's right there.

If `foo` were a template, it would also be simple

```
template <typename T>
void foo (callback_t<T> callback) {
    std::packaged_task<T()> task {
        [] () {return 42;}
    };

    task();
    callback(task.get_future());
}
```

If you really insist on extracting it, you can write a trait.

```
template <typename>
struct callback_arg;

template <typename T>
struct callback_arg<callback_t<T>> { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
using callback_arg_t = typename callback_arg<T>::type;
```

And use it like

```
using int_callback = std::function<void(std::future<int>)>;

void foo (int_callback callback) {
    std::packaged_task<callback_arg_t<int_callback>()> task {
        [] () {return 42;}
    };

    task();
    callback(task.get_future());
}
```

Comment: There is a need: DRY, If I change `int` to `long long` for example, I just have to change it in one place.